# Unity Cross Platform Third Party Login with AWS Cognito Hosted UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, amazon-cognito, federated-identity

I'm trying to build a login scene for my app. Using AWS Cognito user pools I have managed to build a generic sample of code which handles the code exchange for login through Google and Facebook through a URL provided from the hosted UI. For Example:

https://appname.auth.eu-central-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=CODE&scope=openid%20email&redirect_uri=...&...identity_provider=Google/Facebook...

All that is left to implement is how unity will prompt the user with this URL. I want some kind of dialog box to popup and not call Application.OpenURL which simply opens the browser. This is fairly common around android/IOS apps. I have tried looking into some embedded browser solutions for that but it seems overwhelmingly complicated.

My question is what is the simplest and lightest way to achieve the login dialog box, will I have to use embedded browsers like this open source repo: https://github.com/gree/unity-webview. Am I missing something trying to achieve my goal?

I'm sorry that there are no code samples to show, since I still don't know what plugin/UI component to use.